# Dotnet core2 Intellisense broken when reference class libraries .Net Standard 2.0 in web project

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I upgraded my project from `.netcore1.1` to 2 yesterday the migration went well but realized that my `Intellisense` is broken in my controllers that references other class libraries like `Services` or `Models`.
Class libraries that reference other class libraries works fine, seems like it is only when you reference the web project.

I then created a new dotnetcore 2 application added 2 class libraries and referenced it in web project and its doing the same thing.

Is this a bug or something wrong with my Visual studio?
I am running  VS 2017 version 15.3.2(latest)

***UPDATE*** 
I changed my class libraries from .Net Standard 2.0 to .Net Standard 1.6 Then it started working again but i cant use that because i need 2.0

And the plot thickens
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/67061/intellisense-errors-in-net-standard-20.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So turn out that Resharper was the problem, updated my Resharper to 
https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/08/24/resharper-ultimate-2017-2-released/
and that fixed it.